# Is CreateInstance of necessary method for a source filter in directshow?

Tags: com, directshow

I read in a book that `CreateInstance` is a MUST for a source filter in directshow,but when I see this I doubt whetger it's true:

```
CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[] = 
{
    {
        L"Virtual Cam",
        &CLSID_VirtualCam,
        CVCam::CreateInstance,
        NULL,
        &AMSFilterVCam
    },
```

I can name the `CreateInstance` static method arbitrarily,like `CreateInstance22`,right or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.

This field is a pointer to a function of type

`CUnknown* (*)(
  LPUNKNOWN pUnk,
  HRESULT* phr 
);`

So any function of that layout can be used.